# Now that Steam has removed the friends tab from settings how do I disable chat notifications sounds?

Tags: steam

It used to be in settings under the friends tab. The friends tab no longer exists! Where do I find that infuriatingly missing setting now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the "Friends" window (right click Steam), click the cog icon in the upper right, then select the "Notifications" tab on the left.